# Cannot start MySQL Cluster Management Service

Tags: mysql, clustering

Could not determine which nodeid to use for this node. Specify it with --ndb-nodeid= on command line.

This is what EventViewer is saying

Comment: Can you please share your config.ini also the statement you are using to start the Management server

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
/usr/sbin/ndb_mgmd --ndb-nodeid=123
```

or set it based on hostname in config.ini

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.1.123
NodeId=123
```

You could try http://www.severalnines.com/cluster-configurator/